# How to find specific bpy.types.CacheFile from specific object?

Tags: python, blend-files

I'm looking for How to find specific **bpy.types.CacheFile** from specific object?

here is my example, I imported two alembic file into the scene, from the object I would like to find what **bpy.types.CacheFile** class represent for that **specific object**. My purpose is to replace the specific CacheFile into another one, input is any one of the object from that imported alembic object.

So from the object is it any way to find the bpy.types.CacheFile using python code?

[image]

If any one can help, that should be appreciable,

Thanks, Subin

Comment: Hello, looking at the docs I don't think a cache file is linked to an object, how do you  determine which object belongs to which cache file in the first place ?